# How to import rxjs static functions with Node 12 import?

Tags: node.js

I am trying out the new Node 12 module import syntax and cannot get static functions from rxjs to work.

I've tried both Typescript-style import syntax and ideas from the new module documentation.

```
// SyntaxError: The requested module 'rxjs' does not provide an export named 'interval'
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
const x = interval(1000)
```

```
// TypeError: interval is not a function
import interval from 'rxjs';
const x = interval(1000)
```

```
// TypeError: interval is not a function
import interval from 'rxjs/observable/interval.js';
const x = interval(1000)
```

Any idea what the correct way is to import static functions?

UPDATE: One way that works:

```
import Observable from 'rxjs';
const x = Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(() => 
  console.log('' + new Date().toISOString())
)
```